# Select com resultado de um dia da semana

Tags: mysql

Bom tenho um select que me retorna o valor total de pedidos feito na semana atual. Faço da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT
    SUM(valor)
FROM
    pedidos
WHERE
    YEARWEEK(data) = YEARWEEK(NOW())
```

Bom preciso de um select para cada dia da semana, que me retorne o total de cada dia da semana atual.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer isso:

```
SELECT
    DAYOFWEEK(data) as dia, SUM(valor) as total
FROM
    pedidos
WHERE
    YEARWEEK(data) = YEARWEEK(NOW())
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(data)
ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK(data)
```

Comment: Deu certo, ele me retornou os dias em números. Seria 0 para domingo e 6 para sábado?

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve truncar a data usando a função DATE do mysql e usar na cláusula GROUP BY:

```
    SELECT
      DATE(data), SUM(valor)
    FROM
      pedidos
    WHERE
      YEARWEEK(data) = YEARWEEK(NOW())
    GROUP BY DATE(data)
    ORDER BY DATE(data)
```

Comment: Deu certo, porém a resposta do Bins se adequá melhor as minas necessidades, pois ela me retorna dos dias da semana em números.

Comment: Ok, achei que você gostaria de exibir a data do dia.

Comment: Muito obrigado.